# Rewriting a url with htaccess that doesn't start with http to https

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

So ok my problem is this, my urls don't start with http or www at least not in the address bar.

So my old htaccess rewrite rule works fine but is doesn't check the protocol.
So when somebody types in just domain.com it's not redirected to the https url.
How can I fix this, I have tried multiple solutions found on the net but somehow it breaks the site.

So when I type the following urls it does work and removes the "www"

1. www.someurl.com
2. ww.someurl.com/something

When I type the following urls it doesn't work, it still loads from http

1. someurl.com
2. someurl.com/withsomething

Old

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

New

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is why I actually I hate that browsers hide the protocol. http is still there it can't work without it. Did you make sure to turn on RewriteEngine?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```